# Can't write RabbitMQ logs to a file

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I have a docker container running a RabbitMQ instance. I want RabbitMQ to write its logs to a file. Therefore I added the following line to my `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf` file:

```
log.file = /myfolder/myfile.log
```

The problem is that it keeps writing its logs to the console. The folder `myfolder` exists and the root user has the write permission for it.

Comment: Is the file empty?

Comment: It doesn't even create it

Comment: Because actually environment variables take precedence over configuration files. And I have the environment variable RABBITMQ_LOGS set to "-". That is why it prints logs to console. The problem now is that I don't know how to permanently change an environment variable. Because I don't have "~/.bash_profile"  file in my container.

Comment: -env flag on the container run command?

Comment: I have managed to set the RABBITMQ_LOGS environment variable through the "docker-compose.tpl" file. But I still don't see logs.